# Oozie error when trying to run Pig job workflow

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, oozie, hortonworks-data-platform

I am trying to run a simple Pig job using Oozie 4.0. I am running into the following error. I have created the `sharelib` folder on the Oozie server at the location `/usr/lib/oozie/share/`.
I have also pushed the same folder to HDFS at the following locations:

```
/user/hdfs
/user/oozie
/user/mapred
```

I have restarted the Hadoop services on the NameNode, Job Tracker and the DataNodes. I did this with the Oozie service stopped and the brought the Oozie service back up using the command:

```
sudo -u oozie /usr/lib/oozie/bin/oozie-start.sh
```

I am still getting this error.

**cluster_conf.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<configuration>
<property>
    <name>nameNode</name>
    <value>hdfs://localhost:8020</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>resourceManager</name>
    <value>localhost:8050</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>oozie.wf.application.path</name>
    <value>/tmp/workflow.xml</value>
</property>
```

**OozieTestScript.pig**

```
A = load '/tmp/passwd' using PigStorage(':');
B = foreach A generate $0 as id;
dump B;
store B into '/tmp/id5.out';
```

Pig command is simple as shown below. Just note I am keeping the private IPs out of the code copied here.

```
<pig xmlns="uri:oozie:workflow:0.2">
  <job-tracker>172.xx.xx.xx:8050</job-tracker>
  <name-node>hdfs://172.xx.xx.xx:8020</name-node>
  <script>OozieTestScript.pig</script>
</pig>
```

**Logs:**

```
2014-05-15 19:47:47,872  WARN PigActionExecutor:542 - USER[mapred] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[Oozie_workflow_test] JOB[0000000-140515194709114-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000000-140515194709114-oozie-oozi-W@pigAction] Launcher ERROR, reason: Main class [org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.PigMain], main() threw exception, org/apache/pig/Main
2014-05-15 19:47:47,873  WARN PigActionExecutor:542 - USER[mapred] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[Oozie_workflow_test] JOB[0000000-140515194709114-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000000-140515194709114-oozie-oozi-W@pigAction] Launcher exception: org/apache/pig/Main
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/pig/Main
    at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.PigMain.runPigJob(PigMain.java:324)
    at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.PigMain.run(PigMain.java:219)
    at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.LauncherMain.run(LauncherMain.java:37)
    at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.PigMain.main(PigMain.java:76)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.LauncherMapper.map(LauncherMapper.java:226)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:54)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:429)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:341)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:162)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1491)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:157)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.pig.Main
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    ... 17 more

2014-05-15 19:47:47,916 DEBUG ActionCheckXCommand:545 - USER[mapred] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[Oozie_workflow_test] JOB[0000000-140515194709114-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000000-140515194709114-oozie-oozi-W@pigAction] ENDED ActionCheckXCommand for wf actionId=0000000-140515194709114-oozie-oozi-W@pigAction, jobId=0000000-140515194709114-oozie-oozi-W
```

Comment: is your oozie running successfully for other jobs?is your localhost and port numbers correct.you try once with hue if you have

Comment: Are you running Oozie 4 in Hadoop 2.2 or above in a single node cluster? If yes, please check it in a Multi node cluster, because oozie in Hadoop 2 has problem in running on a single node cluster.

Comment: Hi. I actually figured this out. The issue was permissions on the oozie share folder that were incorrect. Fixing those permissions fixed the issue. Thanks so much.